# Consumer group isn't being created in control center - Kafka

Tags: java, intellij-idea, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm currently trying to set up a consumer to consume messages from a topic. My log says it subscribes to the topic successfully

```
[Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=consumer-group] Subscribed to topic(s): MY-TOPIC
```

and it clearly shows it is a part of a group, but when I go to the control center I can't find that group, however I can find the topic that I am subscribed too. It isn't consuming the records from the topic either which I attribute to not being apart of a valid group. I know it is polling the correct topic and I know there is records on the topic as I am constantly putting them on.

Here is my start method

```
   @PostConstruct public void start()
{
    // check if the config indicates whether to start the daemon or not
    if (!parseBoolean(maskBlank(shouldStartConsumer, "true")))
    {
        System.err.println("CONSUMER DISABLED");
        logger.warn("consumer not starting -- see value of " + PROP_EXTRACTOR_START_CONSUMER);
        return;
    }

    System.err.println("STARTING CONSUMER");

    Consumer<String, String> consumer = this.createConsumer(kafkaTopicName,
            StringDeserializer.class, StringDeserializer.class);

    Thread daemon = new Thread(() -> {
        while (true)
        {
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
            if (records.count() > 0) // IS ALWAYS 0, Poll doesn't return records
            {
                printRecord(records);
                records.iterator().forEachRemaining(r -> {
                    System.err.println("received record: " + r);
                });
            }
            else { logger.debug("KafkaTopicConsumer::consumeMessage -- No messages found in topic {}", kafkaTopicName); }
        }
    });

    daemon.setName(kafkaTopicName);
    daemon.setDaemon(true);
    daemon.start();
}
```

Note: createConsumer method is just adding all of my config settings and where I subscribe to my topic.

I have a feeling it has something to do with the thread... I can post some of my config if that would help as well just leave a comment. Thanks